# SharePoint 2013 Health Check and Post Install Checks

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sql-server, installation, configuration

I have to verify a SharePoint 2013 install for an external company and have never done this before. Looking to compile a detailed check list with things people have commonly came across to cause problems, and common issues faced. Key areas to check. I have began to compile a checklist. Any key additions to this?

SharePoint Server Accounts Setup

- SharePoint Farm Service (SecurityAdmin and DB_Creator rights on the SQL Instance)
- SharePoint Administrator Account (Local Administrator on all the SharePoint Servers. SecurityAdmin and DB_Creator rights on the SQL Instance)
- SharePoint Pool Account
- SharePoint Service Applications
- SharePoint Search Service
- SharePoint User Profile
- Check Applications Pool to ensure none running as a user account (Manage services > properties)
- Check Service accounts are not part of local administrators group

SQL Server Accounts Setup

- SQL Administrator Account (Local Administrator on the SQL Server)
- SQL Services Account

Server Setup

- Check SQL type, is it express?
- SQL on separate server

Hardware Checks

- Minimum 12GB RAM for SharePoint Server
- Minimum 4 Cores
- Minimum 8GB RAM for SQL Server (<1000 Users)
- Minimum 4 Cores

Server Versions & Patches

- Confirm all most recent patch and service packs
- Windows Updates all applied

General

- Check Central Admin for messages/warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

couple of things:

- make sure User Profile Sync Services is up and running
- Make Sure Crawl is working.
- Make Sure Distributed Cache is properly configured
- Make sure the Managed Meta Data service is configured and other service application.
- Workflow Manager Configuration (real check only by creating a WF and testing REST)
- check the Event Log for any error( some time related to SSL, Security token service etc)
- perform the testing i.e:

  - creation of web application
  - creation of site collection
  - creation of workflows
  - end user testing.
- Perform the health check on the server i.e ram, cpu etc usages
- perform a load test on the farm
- you can also try to DR on the farm.

Comment: I thought I'd marked this as answer, found it helpful, guided me through the process

Answer (score 1):

I followed following checklist :
-   Check Health Analyzer on servers (WFE, App, SQL etc)
-   Check Search Crawling and indexing
-   Check Event Logs on all servers.
-   Check Memory and hard disk consumption on all server.
-   Check if SQL Back up jobs running successfully.
-   Check if old logs are clearing up.
-   Large Lists Throttling Issues
-   New SharePoint Security updates (Monthly/Quarterly)
-   Review ULS logs, critical SharePoint and SQL Server settings and configurations
-   Remove unused Service Applications.
-   Check for orphan accounts.
-   Check for orphan features.
-   Review Web Analytics reports.

There is one very helpful SharePoint checklist (Daily, Weekly and monthly) available: 
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Sharepoint-Checklist-Daily-56293835